# Realm accessed from incorrect thread occasional

Tags: swift, realm

I have this function

```
class func addCVals(_ criteres: [[AnyHashable: Any]], _ type: String) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        autoreleasepool {
            if criteres.count > 0 {
                if let realm = DBTools.getRealm() {
                    do {
                        try realm.transaction {
                            let oldValues = CriteresVal.objects(in: realm, where: "type = '\(type)'")
                            if oldValues.count > 0 {
                                realm.deleteObjects(oldValues)
                            }
                            for critere in criteres {
                                let cval = CriteresVal(critere, type)
                                if let c = cval {
                                    realm.addOrUpdate(c)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch {
                        DebugTools.record(error: error)
                    }
                    realm.invalidate()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The request that get oldValues occasionally cause an error

> Realm accessed from incorrect thread

I don't understand why as I get a new Realm before with this lines:

```
if let realm = DBTools.getRealm()
```

My function getRealm:

```
class func getRealm() -> RLMRealm? {
    if !AppPreference.lastAccount.elementsEqual("") {
        let config = RLMRealmConfiguration.default()
        do {
            return try RLMRealm(configuration: config)
        } catch {
            DebugTools.record(error: error)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               Notifier.showNotification("", NSLocalizedString("UNKNOWN_ERROR_DB", comment: ""), .warning)
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

CriteresVal is an RLMObject that is composed of this:

```
@objcMembers
public class CriteresVal: RLMObject {
   dynamic var cvalId: String?
   dynamic var type: String?
   dynamic var text: String?
   dynamic var compositeKey: String?

   override public class func primaryKey() -> String {
       return "compositeKey"
   }

   private func updatePrimaryKey() {
       self.compositeKey = "\(self.cvalId ?? "")/\(self.type ?? "")"
   }

   required init(_ cvalue: [AnyHashable: Any]?, _ type: String) {
       super.init()
    
       if let values = cvalue {
           if let cvalId = values["id"] as? String {
               self.cvalId = cvalId
           } else if let cvalId = values["id"] as? Int {
               self.cvalId = "\(cvalId)"
           }
           self.type = type
           if let text = values["text"] as? String {
               self.text = text
           }
       }
    
       updatePrimaryKey()
   }

   func generateDico() -> [String: Any] {
       var dicoSortie = [String: Any]()
       if let realm = self.realm {
           realm.refresh()
       }
    
       if let value = cvalId {
           dicoSortie["id"] = value
       }
       if let value = type {
           dicoSortie["type"] = value
       }
       if let value = text {
           dicoSortie["text"] = value
       }
    
       return dicoSortie
   }
}
```

compositeKey is the primary key which included cvalId and type

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you show us what `CriteresVal.objects(in:where:args:)` does? Is it something implemented by you?

Comment: Realm has no function `DBTools.getRealm()` so we don't know what that does. Can you clarify and update the question with more information?

Comment: @VladRusu I added what is CriteresVal. The function objects(in:where:args:) is a function of Realm

Comment: @Jay I added the content of the function getRealm()

Comment: @Vanilil It would help if you shared the code for the `CriteresVal.objects`. I'm willing to bet that's where the problem is.

Comment: @RobertCrabtree `CriteresVal.objects` is not my code, it's code of Realm there: [https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/ ]

Comment: Does `getVaList([])` do anything Realm related?

Comment: Could you provide more details about `CriteresVal.objects` as it doesn't appear in the API and the link provided is a LOT of projects and code to try to find it in.

Comment: @Jay https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMObject(cm)objectsWhere:

Comment: @Vanilil Why are you using the objc libraries and not the swift libraries?

Comment: @RobertCrabtree I use objc libraries because I still have a lot of objc code in my app

Comment: There's nothing in that link that references `CriteresVal`. That link is for the main RealmObject. Please provide accurate/complete information so we can help identify the issue. You've not included how that is actually defined and this `CriteresVal.objects(in:` is not a valid call for a Realm object. Its's actually not a valid RLMObject function at all - either swift of objc - as you can't fetch other objects directly from an RLMObject so this `CriteresVal.objects(in:` doesn't make sense within that context. It must be a third party library or something you've defined elsewhere in code.

Comment: @Jay `CriteresVal` is a class that I created and which inherits from the RLMObject class. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my post.
The `objects(in:where:args:)` function is valid. It is in the doc that @RobertCrabtree quoted. It allows to retrieve a `RLMResults` object with the realm objects matching the specified criteria. As I call it from the `CriteresVal` class, I get `CriteresVal` objects.

Comment: No, that is not valid and there is no function `objects(in:where:args:)` in that linked documentation to RLMObject (check it). **RLMObject** does not retrieve other objects per se. The RLMObject has a **class** function to define what objects to return as a *results object* like this (ObjC) `RLMResults<Dog *> *puppies = [Dog objectsWhere:@"age < 2"];` or (swift) `let puppies = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age < 2")` but as you can see, neither match your function. Please update your question with that object.

Comment: @RobertCrabtree There's nothing in that documentation link like this `objects(in:where:args:)`. The closest match would be a **class** function `objectsWhere:` which has the usage `(ObjC) RLMResults<Dog *> *puppies = [Dog objectsWhere:@"age < 2"];` The point being the OP has a custom class object that's loading objects from realm on a different thread so I am attempting to get them to post the actual object so we can see the implementation.

Comment: @Jay I added the content of the `CriteresVal` class if it helps.
`objects (in: where: args :)` is valid because `CriteresVal` is the equivalent of `Dog` in your example. `objects (in: where: args :)` is the equivalent of `+ objectsInRealm: where:` for use from Swift. But it seems that now I no longer need `args` argument since I don't really use it and it no longer seems necessary.

Comment: See [Models](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#limitations-models) you should not be using `super.init`, instead `self.init() //Please note this says 'self' and not 'super'.

Comment: @Jay Since I use the objc libraries, in which this is not specified, I don't know if it's relevant, even for use in swift. I'll change it anyway.

Comment: Well, I can't seem to find any reference in the ObjC Realm API [RLMObject class](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html) for `objects(in:` nor can I find any reference to `+objectsInRealm:` in the Swift API (as you mentioned) for [Object class](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html). Perhaps you're using a very old library? Without that info though, the threading issue you're experience will probably continue since we don't know what backs the functions you're using. I even searched here on SO for any references to those. Perhaps I overlooked it.

Comment: @Jay I used `+objectsInRealm:where:`
 from objc API but in I used it in Swift, so it's `objects (in: where:)`

Comment: The last version of Realm changelog say it fix a bug that cause "Realm accessed from incorrect thread." exceptions, so maybe it will fix my issue.

Comment: Finally found it in the 2014 source code files and I think that was fixed in a more current release.

Comment: Seems not fix for my case :(